# Clean Architecture - Reuse exception handling code for a specific use case or repository function

Tags: clean-code, clean-architecture

I am implementing the clean architecture. The use case should not know details about the UI because the UI is in a more outer layer. Same goes for the data layer. For the data, the use case should work through a repository without knowing the details of how the repository works.

I like to err on the side of putting more code in the domain or at least in some more centralised layer than in the View Model/Presenter. That is because the code in the domain or more centralised area is much easier to reuse.

I have this UseCase to create a user:

```
class CreateUserUseCase {
  final IUserRepository _userRepository = Get.put(UserRepository());
  Future<UserCredential> invoke(String email, String password) {
    return _userRepository.createUser(email, password);
  }
}
```

To call it, I do this:

```
loading.value = true;
try {
  final result = await _createUserUseCase.invoke(
      _email, _form.control(_passwordKey).value as String);
  print(result);
  vpSnackBar('Success Creating Account', 'Welcome aboard, $_nickName!');
  loading.value = false;
  await Get.offAllNamed<dynamic>(Routes.HOME);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
    vpSnackBar(
        'Error Creating Account', 'The password provided is too weak.');
  } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    vpSnackBar('Error Creating Account',
        'The account already exists for that email.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  vpSnackBar('Error Creating Account', e.message as String);
  return null;
}
loading.value = false;
return null;
```

Let's say I wanted to call that Use Case all the time, throughout my code, and the user should always be informed of if it worked or had errors, using those exact same sentences as in the code above, and I didn't want to write those error messages and other error handling codes all the time. Would it be frowned upon for me to make an abstraction for informing the user and moving some of my code out of my non-reusable view model, into my reusable use case? I would defer the implementation of informing the user to the outer layers. Not the Use Case.

I find it quite difficult to move that code into the use case because of the different types of exceptions (`FirebaseAuthException`) that the use case should not know about. In this case, can I instead move the copy-pasted exception messages and other exception handling code that will always be the same for that use case out of the view model/presenter and into the repository or data source? Since the repository and data source can know `FirebaseAuthException`? Can the repository or data source know about an abstraction for sending a message to the user, that many different types of UI's can implement themselves?

Or is there some other way that I can call that use case all over my app without having to copy and paste that exception handling code every time?

Comment: I've just thought of a possible option - moving that code to the invoke the use case and handle the exceptions into a small ,specific and centralised view model/presenter called something like "CreateUserController" and then adding that into all of the veiwModel/presenters that perform that task. This would probably not mix layers that shouldn't be mixed.

Comment: There's an inherent contradiction in your outline, where you both argue that (a) use cases should not contain view logic and (b) reusable code should err towards the domain/central layer. If you move logic from one layer to another simply because it's reusable, then you're violating premise (a), which states that logic should remain in the layer it belongs to. You've pointed out the behavior (migrating reusable logic to different layers), you've pointed out the problems with doing so (code not residing in the layer it belongs to), so why are you still trying to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three stages of programming:

1. First, we learn to write working code
2. Then, we learn how to write clean code
3. Finally, we learn to avoid dogma and blanket overzealousness

Based on your question, it seems you're between steps 2 and 3. I'm mentioning this because you're using definitely trying to write clean code, but you seem to slip into a dogmatic approach.

Specifically this:

> I like to err on the side of **putting more code in the domain or at least in some more centralised layer than in the View Model/Presenter**. That is because the code in the domain or more centralised area is much easier to **reuse**.

Reusability is definitely good practice. However, purely from a semantical point, someone who unknowingly violated SRP would call their approach "reusable" because they reuse the same class for a secondary purpose.

What I'm trying to get at here is that promoting reusability is good, but only when it is warranted. Not everything that can be called "reuse" in English is necessarily a good implementation of reusability as a clean coding practice.

I get the feeling that this dogmatic approach to reusability is causing an inherent contradiction in your approach, where you both argue that

1. Use cases should not contain view logic
2. Reusable code should err towards the domain/central layer.

If you move logic from one layer to another simply because it's reusable, then you're violating the key premise of (1), i.e. that logic should remain in the layer it belongs to.

You've pointed out the behavior (migrating reusable logic to different layers), you've pointed out the problems with doing so (code not residing in the layer it belongs to), so what is the alleged benefit here, and is it worth violating the central tenet that code shouldn't live outside the layer it belongs in?

What you're trying to do here is boilerplate your logic. And while that's not impossible to do, it isn't a great approach (there's a reason why "boilerplate" has negative connotations). Just because you *can* use something twice, doesn't mean that you need to abstract it. Sometimes, two things happen to look the same, without them actually being the same. Trying to abstract them or create a common ancestor is a trap in these cases.

Rather than abstracting the control flow itself, which IMHO shouldn't be abstracted, focus on abstracting the components that the flow orchestrates.

The problem with trying to reuse wrapper control logic is that it requires you to inject the wrapped logic, usually in several bits and pieces (e.g. the `try` logic, the `catch` logic, the `if` logic, the `else if` logic, the `else` logic, ...), and **this becomes inhibitively complex and unreadable**.

> Let's say I wanted to call that Use Case all the time, throughout my code, and the user should always be informed of if it worked or had errors, using those exact same sentences as in the code above, and I didn't want to write those error messages and other error handling codes all the time.

If you want the messages to be reused, abstract *the messages*. Not the code surrounding them.

How you best tackle this is a bit language- and framework-dependent, as string resource handling is a common enough use case that generalized approaches exist.
But at a very basic level, you can always create a static (readonly) property with the message you want to reuse. This can be implemented in myriad ways:

- As a static class which acts as a string collections (e.g. .NET has "resource files" which act as such)
- As static properties on the class in question. This enables outside callers to access this static information related to the class in question (without it needing to be returned via method call)
- As part of a base class, which ensures that all of its derived classes can reuse its specific error messages.

One example would be:

```
public static class CreateUserUseCase
{
    public static readonly string Success = "Success Creating Account";
    public static readonly string Error = "Error Creating Account";

    public static string GenerateGreeting(string name) => $"Welcome aboard, {name}!"

    public static string WeakPasswordError = "The password provided is too weak.";
    public static string EmailInUseError = "The account already exists for that email.";
}
```

However, most of the reusability in your particular example pertains to validation logic. I am unsure if this is coincidental or if it's true about most of the logic you seek to make reusable.

If it is often validation-related, then you should really look into making separate validator classes which can be reused in your use cases.

Whatever the component is that you want to make reusable, the approach remains the same: look at precisely what needs to be reused, find an appropriate pattern that matches your implementation, and then abstract it.

But **beware abstraction for abstraction's sake**. It's very easy to slip into abstracting things because you think good developers always abstract things and not considering whether it actually adds value or not.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking generally, another very important consideration in cases like this is to *"avoid* ***coupling."***

When you "re-use" something, you run the risk of "coupling" all of the different areas of the system which re-use that same thing.  You also risk introducing case-specific logic into the "re-used thing," merely because it enables you to "re-use it," when the logic really doesn't belong there.

Always think about the "subsequent programmer" who's going to have to modify what you've done to do something that *(of course)* you hadn't thought of.  What is **always** going to be front-and-center for this person is – *"if I change this, what else might it break?"*  You really want to be nice to that future-person and keep the "footprint" as small as possible. The word "clean" definitely includes: *"maintainable, future-proof."*